# RODBC ERROR: 'Calloc' could not allocate memory

Tags: sql-server, r, database, azure-sql-database, rodbc

I am setting up a SQL Azure database. I need to write data into the database on daily basis. I am using 64-bit R version 3.3.3 on Windows10. Some of the columns contain text (more than 4000 characters). Initially, I have imported some data from a csv into the SQL Azure database using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studios. I set up the text columns as ntext format, because when I tried using nvarchar the max was 4000 and some of the values got truncated even though they were about 1100 characters long.

In order to append to the database I am first saving the records in a temp table when I have predefined the varTypes:

```
varTypesNewFile <- c("Numeric", rep("NTEXT", ncol(newFileToAppend) - 1)) 
names(varTypesNewFile) <- names(newFileToAppend) 
sqlSave(dbhandle, newFileToAppend, "newFileToAppendTmp", rownames = F, varTypes = varTypesNewFile, safer = F)
```

and then append them by using:

```
insert into mainTable select * from newFileToAppendTmp
```

If the text is not too long, the above does work. However, sometimes I get the following error during the sqlSave command:

```
Error in odbcUpdate(channel, query, mydata, coldata[m, ], test = test,  : 
'Calloc' could not allocate memory (1073741824 of 1 bytes)
```

My questions are:

1. How can I counter this issue?
2. Is this the format I should be using?
3. Additionally, even when the above works, it takes about an hour to upload about 5k of records. Is it not too long? Is this the normal amount of time it should take? If not, what could I do better.

Answer (score 1):

RODBC is very old, and can be a bit flaky with NVARCHAR columns. Try using the [RSQLServer](https://cloud.r-project.org/package=RSQLServer) package instead, which offers an alternative means to connect to SQL Server (and also provides a dplyr backend).

Comment: As the CRAN version is not available I tried: devtools::install_github('imanuelcostigan/RSQLServer') 
This gives: "ERROR: dependency 'dbplyr' is not available for package 'RSQLServer'"
Then: devtools::install_github('tidyverse/dbplyr') results in:
"ERROR: dependency 'glue' is not available for package 'dbplyr'"
And then: "WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages, but is not currently installed." 
Installing Rtools now.

Comment: RSQLServer IS on CRAN. Try install.packages again.

Comment: > install.packages("RSQLServer")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/ds/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘RSQLServer’ is not available (for R version 3.3.3)

Comment: If you're using Microsoft R, your repo points to an old MRAN snapshot. Set the repo to cloud.r-project.org.

Comment: You were right. I was using another mirror. 
"RSQLServer" is installed and I'll give it a try now.
Thanks.